# ¿Qué significa la frase "Estoy más puesta que un calcetín"?

Tags: traducción, modismos, méxico

Una amiga mexicana me dijo la frase "Estoy más puesta que un calcetín."  ¿Qué significa eso?

El contexto es que ella me ofrece una lección de baile.

> Ella: Yo te doy unas clasesitas de baile.
>
> Yo: Me gustaría tomar tu clase.
>
> Ella: Cuando gustes, amigo. Estoy más puesta que un calcetín.

Comment: La expresion "puesto como el calcetín" lo he escuchado en varias peliculas mexicanas. Una de ellas era con Mario Moreno Cantiflas. Ningún mexicano le ha dado un significado inmoral o sucio a esa expresion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yo soy de México (al igual que tu amiga), y estoy en desacuerdo con la mayoría de las respuestas.

Primero y muy importante, esta frase NO tiene para nada una connotación sexual.

Otros te responden acerca de la frase "Estar `puesto` en algo", pero creo que tampoco aplica aquí ya que la frase completa "Estoy más puesta que un calcetín" tiene un significado particular, NO es una frase que puedas dividir y analizarla por partes.

La frase simplemente significa **que está totalmente dispuesta o de acuerdo a participar o ayudar en lo que se este hablando**.

En tu caso significa que ella está **totalmente de acuerdo o dispuesta en darte las clases de baile**

Comment: Please check my answer for extra precision of the expression, and the meaning of "puesto".

Answer (score 8):

La frase indica que ella está lista para ayudarte cuando sea, en cualquier momento.

Answer (score 0):

Entre otras cosas, "[puesto](http://dle.rae.es/puesto)" en español significa:

> adj. Bien vestido, ataviado o arreglado.

Creo, sin ninguna duda, que es esta la acepción a la que se refiere.

Estar bien vestido o arreglado se asocia de manera figurada con **estar preparado para algo**. Arreglado para salir de casa, bien vestido para dar una conferencia, etc...

El "doble juego" de palabras, la "gracia" del asunto consiste en comparar dos acepciones diferentes de la misma palabra (puesto), una para cosas y otra para personas que no tienen por qué significar lo mismo. Un calcetín está puesto (colocado), igual que una persona está puesta (preparada) de manera figurada.

Es exactamente el mismo caso que la frase:

> Estoy más colgado que una percha.

Yo lo traduciría de la siguiente forma:

> **"Estar más puesto que un calcetín" = "Estar listo y tener ganas de hacerlo ahora o en cuanto el otro esté listo"**

En inglés sería algo así:

> I'm (completely) ready (and looking forward) to do it. (So let's begin whenever you're ready!)

Esta acepción encaja perfectamente y da completo sentido al ejemplo que se ha puesto:

> Cuando gustes, amigo. Estoy más puesta que un calcetín.
>
> **= Cuando gustes, amigo. Yo estoy lista, ¡podemos empezar cuando quieras!.**

Answer (score 0):

EN MÉXICO:
Más puesta/o que un calcetín: Estoy dispuesto/a, nada más falta que me digas, cuando quieras.
Y PARA NADA, no tiene ningún doble sentido o connotación sexual. No todo es albur.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí hay que ver la relación con "puesta". Yo he oído y dicho

> Estoy puestísimo!

no estoy seguro pero podría ser una contracción de dispuesto, no estoy seguro de si sea ese el origen pero el significado es el mismo. Si alguien esta "puesto" quiere decir que **esta dispuesto a ayudarte**.

Entonces con

> Estoy más puesta que un calcetín

Ella hace referencia al hecho de que un calcetín está fijo y no se mueve, quiere decir que está bastante dispuesta a ayudarte con mucho gusto, si ella le agregó todo eso quiere decir que **realmente tiene muchas ganas de ayudarte**, es de alguna manera un intensificador.

Es como un juego buscando ideas que queden aunque algunas veces no combinan, y si quieres dar a entender la idea contraria sólo haces la comparación con algo que no es tan firme.

Answer (score -1):

Yo por el contrario entiendo por la frase no su disposición (aunuqe va implicito) a la tarea en si sino su habilidad para hacerlo. Estar puesto en una materia en este caso el baile, me trasmite el significado de conocer el tema.

Comment: Realmente "estar más puesto que un calcetín" tiene que el significado que indican en México, es la frase tal cual.

Comment: @JoulSauron Significa estar puesto en materia. Se le agrega lo de calcetin porque queda ajustado. Pero es estar puesto en materia. http://www.cosasdeandalucia.com/web/index.php/component/glossary/Expresiones-21/E/Estar-puesto-1716/

Comment: Lo normal es que si alguien esta listo para hacer algo la palabra sea dispuesto no puesto

Comment: No, es una expresión tal cual. Hay más referencias de ese uso: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=204510&langid=24

Comment: Hombre la referencia como que no. Es un foro tal cual. no más es un foro. La RAE si bien en su primera acepción dice: 1. adj. Resuelto, empeñado, determinado.  y en la tercera que es la que me parece se ajusta. 3. adj. coloq. Experto o buen conocedor de la materia o asunto que se expresa. Muy puesto EN matemáticas. Por ningún lugar puesto como sinónimo de dispuesto, pudiera ser que en Mexico fueran sinónimos, si no lo fuera y el significado fuera estar dispuesto de plano entonces la frase sería un sinsentido.

Comment: Es un ejemplo para que vieras que en México lo emplean así y no hay que darle más vueltas. "Más puesto que un calcetín" = "dispuesto".

Comment: No yo no le doy vueltas, Bueno al menos le doy las mismas vueltas que usted, solamente que puesto no es sinónimo de dispuesto, y la RAE estar puesto lo define como conocer una materia.  dispuesto, ta.

(Del part. irreg. de disponer; lat. disposĭtus). http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=dispuesto

Comment: @ErnestoMarreno Aqui en Mexico el principal significado de la esa frase es el estar "dispuesto", no el ser "experto". Aqui en mexico alguien puede decir "Estoy mas puesto que un calcetin para jugar futbol" y eso no implica que la persona sea un experto en futbol, esa persona puede incluso nunca haber jugado en su vida, pero esta "dispuesta" a hacer el intento.

Comment: ¿Por que me dices que es el principal significado ? ¿Tiene otros significados? Sigo buscando y no veo puesto como sinónimo de dispuesto.

Comment: @ErnestoMarreno Como puedes ver dos de las tags de esta pregunta son "Mexico" y "Modismos", entonces tal vez por ahi deberias empezar tu busqueda. Ademas, dije "principal significado", porque **aqui en Mexico**, puede llegar incluso a significar que tienes muchas ganas o estas ansioso de realizar algo.

Comment: @Dante me has puesto en el apellido antes Moreno y ahora Marreno, casi me dices Marrano. Es broma. Si ya he mirado por monton de sitios que en México significa estar dispuesto. Lo cual no me impide seguir pensando que la frase tal como está construida y con el significado del español, lleva a un sinsentido. Mi apellido es m-a-r-r-e-r-o

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero no todo tiene que ser lógico. Es simplemente un modismo.

Comment: @ErnestoMarrero Me disculpo por el error en tu apellido. Por otro lado, AlfredoOsorio tiene razon. Comprende que es un "modismo". Tal como lo define Wikipedia un modismo se define como una expresión fija, privativa de una lengua, **cuyo significado no se deduce de las palabras que la forman**. Ojala esta definicion ayude a aclarar este asunto un poco mas.

Comment: Si ya ahora despues de leer la definición de modismo tambien en la RAE comprendo porque no le veo sentido. modismo.

1. m. Expresión fija, privativa de una lengua, cuyo significado no se deduce de las palabras que la forman; p. ej., a troche y moche.

2. m. idiotismo (‖ giro o expresión contrario a las reglas gramaticales); p. ej., a ojos vistas. http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=modismo

Answer (score -3):

En este caso, "estar puesto en algo" indica "tener mucho conocimiento de algo". Yo estoy puesto en informática. Así, "estar más puesto que un calcetín" es un juego de palabras entre dos acepciones de "puesto", la de conocimientos y la de ser usado como prenda de vestir. Como el calcetín es una prenda que se utiliza mucho, el juego de palabras indica que el hablante tiene muchísimo conocimiento de la materia en cuestión.

Comment: La expresión es "estar más puesto que un calcetín" que se usa en México. Tu respuesta ya ha salido antes en varias ocasiones y no es eso, repondes a otra expresión. ;)

Answer (score -4):

En Argentina puede significar que está borracha o que está muy excitada.

Answer (score -6):

EDIT: Lo siguiente no será valido en México tal vez, pero si se aplica a MUCHOS paises de habla hispana:

La expresión "estar puesto" tiene varios significados. Puede ser saber mucho, como dijo JoulSauron, pero también se utiliza hace años para hacer referencia a que alguien quien se encuentra drogrado ("Anoche en el boliche Pedro estaba puesto"). También puede ser usada para expresar deseo sexual ("Anita me tiene puesto"). Personalmente creo que este último es el que mejor encaja por el conexto. Finalmente, la parte 'más que un calcetín' es muy típico del latino, utilizar comparaciones para exagerar lo que se dice ("Estoy más loco que una cabra", "Estoy más frío que una heladera", "Tiene más tetas que una vaca", y un sinfín de etcéteras, tantos como alcance la imaginación).

> Ella: Yo te doy unas clasesitas de baile.
>
> Yo: Me gustaría tomar tu clase.
>
> Ella: Cuando gustes, amigo. Estoy más puesta que un calcetín.

En resumen, y visto desde este punto de vista, creo que esa respuesta "Estoy más puesta que un calcetín" ha sido un coqueteo o insunuación sexual.

Comment: Bueno yo que soy de México no creo que sea el caso que sea una insinuación sexual. Nosotros utilizamos el "Estoy bien puesto" cuando nos referimos a que "Estamos bien listos (para realizar una actividad)."

Comment: -1 En Mexico esto no es una insinuancion sexual.

Comment: ¿Acaso México es el unico lugar en el mundo donde se habla español?

Comment: @Zukki Si lees la pregunta nuevamente dice `Una amiga mexicana ...`, ademas, uno de los tags de la pregunta es: `Mexico`

Comment: @Zukki, en este sitio, así como en otros de la red StackExchange, las respuestas deben ser precisas con respecto a la pregunta. Tu respuesta respondería a otra pregunta. Si quieres puedes hacerla y contestarla tú mismo.

Comment: El saber no ocupa espacio señores.